# Prevent browser elements being focused on tab navigation in webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, browser, navigation

I have a website and while testing I noticed that if I use tab navigation selection goes throughout my inputs and elements and after the last one focus goes to browser address bar and in some cases (browsers) other browser related elements.

Is there a way to avoid focusing browser elements?

I suppose there should be a way to do this, because I am using Visual Studio Team Services and in case of open popup tab navigation, the navigation doesn't go outside the popup.
I also noticed that if I open a popup dialog in my website even the elements outside the popup (the page from which the popup is called and is staying behind) are being focused.

I hope someone could help deal with this